# Arrays inside Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm doing this assignment and it wants me to store grades (integers that a user enters) into arrays that are named levelOne, levelTwo, levelThree, levelFour. It's also asking me to make calculations, based on the input grades, such as average grade and median grade. Instead of finding the average of each array, I'm trying to store all the data into a "parent" array (where the other arrays should be stored) so I can do all that in one calculation. Is that possible, and if so, how can I do this?

This is how my "children" arrays look:

```
  List<Integer> levelFour = new ArrayList();
  List<Integer> levelThree = new ArrayList();
  List<Integer> levelTwo = new ArrayList();
  List<Integer> levelOne = new ArrayList();
  List<Integer> levelR = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How were you thinking of calculating this? Do you have any problems with actually implementing it, or just the concept?

Comment: How do you think it should work? We can't see your code, or what you're thinking.

Comment: You can always have an array of arrays.  But I don't think that will help you with calculations.  But also note that you can pass an array as a parameter to a subroutine, and have that subroutine calculate, say, the average.  One subroutine can then be used for any of your "level" arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<List<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList();
arr.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
...
```

add integers with, for example

```
arr.get(0).add(4);
```

and, to iterate over elements

```
for (List<Integer> l : arr) {
    for (Integer i : l) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will do much for the OP.  (Even though it's more or less what he's asking for.)

Answer (score 1):

If your assignment mentions array and your course specifically uses Java then `List` and its implementation `ArrayList` might not be exactly what you want.

An *array of arrays of ints* is declared like this:

```
int[][] arrays = new int[NUMBER_OF_ARRAYS][SIZE_OF_EACH_ARRAY];
```

since `int` is a base type it has a default value (which is 0) that is deferent than null (basetypes cannot be null).

for iterating use:

```
for(int[] array: arrays){
    for(int i: array){
        //do something
    }
}
```

or the more classic and detailed (and customizable):

```
int current = -1;
for(int i =0; i < NUMBER_OF_ARRAYS; i++){
     for(int j =0; j < SIZE_OF_EACH_ARRAY; j++){
         current = arrays[i][j];
         //do something
     }
}
```